# Installing CKEDITOR plugin "JS+Quick Image Upload"

Tags: javascript

Attempting to install this plugin.

Instructions say:

> Upload the contents of the plugin archive to ckeditor/plugins folder... You should end up with the following path then: `ckeditor/plugins/jsplus_image_editor`.

The download zip file is named `jsplus_ckeditor_image`. It contains 3 folders:

- `doksoft_uploader_asp.net`
- `jsplus_image`
- `jsplus_uploader`

I tried uploading any or all of these files, but it won't give me the path `ckeditor/plugins/jsplus_image_editor`.

Seems I have a very basic problem, and I'm sure its my fault. It always is.

TIA

Andrew McG

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://js.plus/products/image-editor/install-ckeditor), you're supposed to upload the archived files **directly** to `ckeditor/plugins`. Don't worry about not ending up with a `ckeditor/plugins/jsplus_image_editor` folder; that will be automatically generated once you enable the plugin.

To enable the plugin after uploading the files, you need to edit `ckeditor/config.js` to add the following code:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'jsplus_image_editor';
```

Hope this helps!